# I want to open another form based on another form value in Access

Tags: ms-access

Hello I have a form in access that drop list value. "Transer","Promo", and "New". If the user choose transfer or promo, it will open another form call old info and in that form it should transfer the same ID that the user entered first time. Can anyone help me please

Answer (score 2):

```
DoCmd.OpenForm strMyFormName, , ,"ID = " & intMyID
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa220276(v=office.11).aspx

You can access the value you passed in `intMyID` using `Me.OpenArgs`.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa160845(office.10).aspx